# Android Device Chooser Shows Red X In Target Column

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I've recently built an Android app with a minSdkVersion of 7 and targetSdkVersion of 10.  I'm now making the app tablet compatible and adding action bars.  So I updated by targetSdkVersion to 15 and in my project properties, moved my Project Build Tarket to Android 4.0.3, API 15.  I also double-checked that my Java Compiler is 1.6.

Without making any other changes to my code, I try to run my app and in the Android Device Chooser, my two physical devices, versions 2.3.4 and 3.1, both have a red X in the Target column, instead of the green check mark.

I'm also working with the ActionbarCompat sample app and a sample app from ActionbarSherlock and when I run one of those apps, both of my devices, show a green check mark.  Both of these sample apps have their Project Build Target set to 4.0.3 and the same sdkVersion settings that I have in my app.  As far as I can tell, my app is setup the same as the others.  Why does my app then have a red X next to my device versions in the Target column.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your app refer to any library project? If it does, I wonder if you can check whether you have `manifestmerger.enabled=true` in your project.properties file and see if adding/removing it make a difference.

Comment: @Joe I just saw this comment. Adding manifestmerger.enabled=true didn't change anything.  I am including the ActionBarSherlock library and by nature, Android's support library.  The red X's showed up before I started including any libraries, as soon as I changed my Project Build Target and updated my manifest.

Comment: can you give the link of the actionbarcompat that you are testing ?

Comment: @JorgeAguilar Go into Eclipse, click File -> New -> Other and choose "Android Sample Project".  Choose either 4.0.3 or 4.1 and click Next.  Choose "ActionBarCompat" near the top and click finish.  A new project will appear in Eclipse, check it's Manifest file and test with any device, you should get a green check mark and not a red x.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Eclipse, after changing the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

if the "Android Device Chooser" still shows the Red X on the Devices (which should be compatibles). Try:

- Open the "Debug Configuration" or "Run Configuration" Dialog
- Remove all the configurations under "Android Application"
- Retry Right-Click on the Project > Debug As > Android Application

All compatible devices should turns to the green check mark now.

Comment: That was it!!!  Thank you very much for posting this response!  Everyone, please up vote this answer!

Comment: @Hiep do you mind explaining why it worked if you know the reason?

Comment: @JDenais I assumed that the "Debug Configuration" cached the old minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion, so after changing them, you should re-create the "Debug Configuration" (Right-Click on the Project > Debug As > Android Application)

Answer (score 3):

It's becuase your devices are running Android versions 2.3.4, and 3.1, 
so you must have minSdkVersion="10" at the very least. Once you set the minSdkVersion
to 10, then you'll get the green check mark again.

Comment: The question mentioned that minSdkVersion is already set to 7, no?

Comment: @Joe is right, I already had minSdkVersion set to 7.  Setting it to 3 didn't help either.  The sample code I mentioned above is min 3, target 14 and I get green checks for that code.  I can't figure out what's different between the sample code and my code.

Answer (score 1):

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

If your manifest have a higher "targetSdkVersion" than your device, it will show a "red cross(X)" next to the firmware.

If your minSdkVersion is higher that your device it will not even run

**UPDATE:**

I tested the sample project and got the same results as my answer clarified since the beginning.
[(image of the project running with same specifications as the question)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4962229/redCrossAndroid.png)

Comment: That's incorrect, if you load up the ActionBarCompat sample, you'll see it uses minSdkVersion of 3 and targetSdkVersion of 14.  When I run that application, on the same devices as I run my application, I get green check marks.  As soon as I then run my application, I get red x's.

Comment: well all the test i did if i change in project > properties > Android the "project build target" to a higher target than my device the red cross appears, but if is lower then a green check appears. have you done that ? or just changed the manifest ? cause the manifest do not update the project build target.

Comment: i do not see why a -1 any ways. This is the first one someone gives me.

Comment: -1 because your answer was not correct.  I'm basing that on my work with the code from the ActionBarCompat sample.  That project is set to min 3 and target 14 and the project build target is set to 14 and I get green checks all the way, for any device.  Also you first comment responding to my first comment wasn't necessary if you had read my original question.  I stated there that yes I had changed my Project Properties and my manifest file.  -1 so another user doesn't read your answer and think it's correct.