# Eclipse "Android Device Chooser" - Red cross infront of all devices in Target column

Tags: java, android

when I run my android development project (with eclipse) at the time when the **android device chooser** loads, it shows my running emulator and the device followed by a red cross as indicated in the following screenshot.

[image]

But when I select the device and run, it installs it and run properly.

In the manifest file I have included the followings.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Just to test I created another new test app project and while creating the new project I selected **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** with the same values. So in the manifest file both are same.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

But the thing is when I run the new test app, it shows the device and the running emulator in proper way with a green tick as follows. Also it shows the device list available under "**Launch a new Android Virtual Device**" section. Bit confused with this and trying to sort out this. Have anyone experienced this before. Appreciate any help to get this done. Thanks inadvance..!!!

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this question, it might have some information for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978600/android-device-chooser-shows-red-x-in-target-column

Comment: Did you created your application using google api ?? due to that also you will get this kind of issues

Comment: Hi itsrajesh4uguys, No its not a google API project. Normal open source one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these in the same order and update the result:

1. Run `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` and see if that fixes it.
2. Let Eclipse run your emulator instead of running it manually.
3. Recreate your AVD with older versions of the SDK and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Gridtestmail, Thanks for the response. Could you please explain how to perform your first point. I am not that familiar with that. Thanks.

Comment: open command prompt and find the path of the adb tool in <sdk>/platform-tools/ in your installation and type exactly like I mentioned.

Comment: I followed the first step but didn't make any diffrence. But when I go to "Run -> Run configurations" Target tab.... and select "Always prompt to pick device" radio button, the problem occurs. If I select "Automatically pick compatible device: Always use..." option it appears in green tick and its alright....Thanks.

Comment: Great the second step was the one that helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. try to restart eclipse, sometimes eclipse has problems with loading  the correct libs directory
2. check the `project.properties` file which target  is config,  it should be

> android-15`

also try fix project properties from  android menu

Comment: Hi Tomer Mor Thanks. I checked that. Thats ok. Seems like its not the problem.